# Local Fontaine--Mazur?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

Given a finite extension $K$ of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, is there some conjectural statement characterizing which finite-dimensional $p$-adic representations of the absolute Galois group of $K$ are (Tate twists of) subquotients of the cohomology groups of $K$-varieties?

Comment: Varieties give rise to de Rham and thus potentially semi-stable representations, but not every such representation comes from geometry: for example, the eigenvalues of Frobenius should be Weil numbers. I don't know any conjectural description.

Comment: The answer to the question in the body of the text is "at present, no" (even for crystalline representations).

Comment: @Olivier is there a reference discussing this? What are the obstructions beyond those provided by Weil conjectures?