# Failure of local Fontaine Mazur

Tags: nt.number-theory, galois-representations, p-adic-hodge-theory

This question unfortunately has a very similar name to [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/331917/local-fontaine-mazur), but I what want to ask here is different.

Let $K$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. It seems to be well known that the local version of the Fontaine-Mazur conjecture is false, in the sense that if $\rho:Gal(\overline{K}/K)\rightarrow GL_d(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ is some de Rham representation, it may very well be that $\rho$ does not come from a variety defined over a $p$-adic field. For instance, this is claimed by Mark Kisin in his survery paper "What is... a Galois representation?".

Maybe this question is naive, but can anyone give me a concrete example of such a representation?

Also, a slightly unrelated question: does one expect the answer to this version of the local Fontaine-Mazur conjecture to change if we allow representations coming from the etale cohomology of **analytic** spaces?

Comment: Take a crystalline representation. If it comes from a global object, the eigenvalues of Frobenius should be algebraic numbers (over the rationals). So just choose a crystalline representations not having this last property.

Comment: Dear @LaurentBerger, thank you for your comment. In the case of a variety defined over $\mathbb{Q}_p$, but not necessarily over $\mathbb{Q}$, would it still be true that the eigenvalues are algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ (and not just over $\mathbb{Q}_p$)? (Note in my question above I asked also about representations coming from varieties defined over $\mathbb{Q}_p$, as in Kisin's article alluded to above)

Comment: Good point! I don't know what happens for varieties over $Q_p$.

Comment: What if we consider representations coming from rigid analytic varieties? Does that have more of a chance of making some version of local Fontaine-Mazur true?

Comment: What if we consider crystalline representations with integral characteristic polynomial of Frobenius with Weil number roots?

Comment: Did the author come up with an answer to the question since?